# Adding Caption and/or description to printer using Powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

I'm at a loss.  I figured using either set-printer or set-printerproperty I would be able to modify the caption and description fields for a printer (ultimately 1000's of printers), but I keep hitting a wall.  Nether caption or description are a parameter or propertyname (when using set-printerproperty) according to the error message.  But when I run both through Get-member, it looks like they are.

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName dcr-team-tst-01 -Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"  | gm
Get-PrinterProperty -ComputerName dcr-team-tst-01 -printername "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"  | gm
```

So if I can't set those properties from either of those set commands anyone know where I can modify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Caption` and `Description` is just an inherited property from the the `CIM_ManagedSystemElement` class. `Description` is available on printer objects, but from what I know, it is set by the driver. That's why it just says "Unavailable" when you look go into Properties of the printer.

To sum up: you can not use the `Caption` and `Description` properties. Use `Comment` and `Location` to provide information.

**EDIT** Source: [MSDN Win32_Printer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Description
>
> Data type: string
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Description of an object. This property is inherited from
>   CIM_ManagedSystemElement.

And

> Caption
>
> Data type: string
>
> Access type: Read-onlyQualifiers: MaxLen (64)
>
> Short description of an object—a one-line string. This property is
>   inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I was hoping to find.  I would love to use the location or comment field but they are already in use by the client and they don't want me to append to them so I was trying to find an unused column that I could use and those two looked perfect.